# Beta distribution central moment

Tags: beta-distribution, moments

I am studying the note "On the sub-Gaussianity of the Beta and Dirichlet distributions" written by Olivier Marchal and Julyan Arbel(2017) which is available [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.00048.pdf).

In page 5, it says
$$ E\Bigg[\Big(X-\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{2j}\Bigg]=\frac{(2j)!}{2^{2j}j!}\frac{\Gamma(2\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha+j)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(2(\alpha+j))}=\frac{(2j)!}{2^{2j}j!}\frac{(\alpha)_j}{(2\alpha)_{2j}}$$
where $X \sim Beta(\alpha, \alpha)$, and $(\alpha)_j=\alpha(\alpha+1)...(\alpha+j-1)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+j)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$.

Can someone tell me what algebra can make the expectation as RHS.

Answer (score 4):

The Beta$(\alpha,\alpha)$ density, defined on the interval $[0,1],$ is

$$f_\alpha(t) = \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\alpha)}\, t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{\alpha-1}$$

where the normalizing constant is the Beta function, known to equal

$$B(\alpha,\alpha) = \int_0^1 t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{\alpha-1}\,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\,\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(2\alpha)}.\tag{*}$$

The substitution $t = (1+\sin\theta)/2$ is a one-to-one mapping from $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ to $[0,1]$ that re-expresses the expectation as

$$\begin{aligned}
E_{f_\alpha}\left[\left(X-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2j}\right] &= \int_0^1 \left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2j}\,f_\alpha(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{2j+2\alpha-1}B(\alpha,\alpha)}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^{2\alpha-1}(\theta)\,\sin^{2j}(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&= \frac{B\left(j+\frac{1}{2},\alpha\right)}{2^{2j+2\alpha-1}B(\alpha,\alpha)}.
\end{aligned}$$

(The trigonometric integral is well known; see, for instance, Whittaker & Watson **12.42**.)

Use the formula $(*)$ and the Gamma recurrence

$$\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$$

to re-express this in the form given in the question.

---

#### Reference

E. T. Whittaker  & G. N. Watson, *A Course of Modern Analysis.* Fourth Edition (1927).

Comment: Thank you very much. I fully understand the transformation. Since I didn't know $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)=\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!}$, it took a little bit more time to reach the end of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more precise answer: the central moments of beta distribution can be expressed in terms of the hypergeometric function.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaDistribution.html

The setup $\alpha=\beta$ from the question follows then as in such a case formulas greatly simplify (well-known special cases).